# working out a calculation based on two mysql fields

Tags: php, mysql, database, math

I want to work out an average "rating" for my cocktails in a table. There is a tblRating linked to tblCocktail and within this table is "value" and "counter". "value" contains the 1-5 rating a user can give each cocktail, and "counter" contains the value "1". I want to work out the average rating for each cocktail by adding up all the "value"s and dividing it by the number of "counter"s

I've never done mathematical calculations based on php fields before so any help is appreciated

-matt

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably do not need the counter field, the [`AVG`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_avg) function can calculate averages without requiring a counter:

```sql
SELECT AVG(value)
FROM tblRating
WHERE cocktail_id = 1234
```

Notes:

- You can count the number of rows inside the rating table to determine the number of ratings
- `NULL` values are not taken into account when average is calculated
- You must stick with your chosen scale and not allow values outside the 1-5 range

Answer (score 1):

Here's an exaple that should do what you want, obviusly without having the full table schema it is not possible being more accurate, but the example should show the idea :

```
SELECT c.name, AVG(r.value)
FROM tblCocktail c
JOIN tblRating r ON c.id = r.cocktail.id
GROUP BY c.id, c.name
```

Basically you are selecting all cocktail from tblCocktail and calculating the average of the rating(r.value).

Comment: apologies I should have put my table field names in, "cocktailID" is the primary/foreign key linked, and "value" / "counter" are the fields that are having rating data put into them. Im not quite sure where this code needs to be implemented, and what variable/value needs to be echo'd for the average.